# Understanding "why else would"

Tags: meaning, questions

I have a question about this highlighted part of an ESL pod transcript:

> Mandy: Whoo! Whoo!  
>   Theo: Hey, get down from there. You shouldn’t be sticking your head out of the sunroof.  
>   Mandy: I just wanted to get some air. This stretch limo is amazing.  
>   Theo: Well, I thought I’d rent one and take you to the prom in style.
>   Mandy: This is the height of luxury. You’ve really outdone yourself.  
>   Theo: Thanks, but maybe we should be careful not to spill drinks on the seats.   
>   Mandy: Everybody drinks and parties in the back of a limo. **Why else would they have a wet bar?**  
>   Theo: Well, we shouldn’t be drinking out of it. We could get into trouble.  
>   Mandy: The chauffeur doesn’t know what we’re doing back here.

Does ** why + else + would  has a grammar usage? 
And what does this question mean? 
As it is very difficult to understand could you please provide me with some more examples?

Comment: Does it have the same meaning with otherwise?

Answer (score 6):

"Why else" is a common construction in conversational English, meaning, "for what other reason". Read that sentence as "For what other reason would they have a wet bar?" This is a **[rhetorical question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question)**, i.e. a question that has only one possible answer, used to prove a point. There *is* a wet bar in the limo, so if it's *not* to provide drinks, what other purpose could it have? One could say this is rhetorical use of [Occam's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor); Mandy uses it in a cutting manner.